# c# получение dom в winform

Tags: c#, winforms

Хотел бы узнать есть ли какой либо другой элемент работы с DOM на с# кроме WebBrowser. Причина следующая: WebBrowser использует движок IE и давально старый, и нужный мне сайт не адоптирован под IE. Направьте о чем почитать, может есть библиотеки внешние. Вот например webKit (что-то подобное ей). Если кто знает, буду рад любой информации.

Comment: Есть CefSharp на базе Chromium: http://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/

Comment: @АндрейNOP спасибо большое )

Comment: Справедливости ради, web browser использует тот движок, [который указан в мета тегах](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771258/what-does-meta-http-equiv-x-ua-compatible-content-ie-edge-do), ну или старый, если там ничего не указано